# Button press effect like ios

Tags: android, button, rippledrawable

I'm trying to add press effect to my button I have a button with `android:drawableStart="@drawable/my_image"` and I've added

> `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
>   android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`

lines but didn't worked. Also I created a drawalbe for ripple effect with below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:color="@color/solid_red">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    </item>
</ripple>
</selector>

android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
android:foreground="@drawable/ripple_effect"
```

but this is supports only if api under 21 and even if it's works it's now showing up because of image and also I want to add to foreground but when I added it It's covering whole image I just want to create a simple button press effect like ios default button press effect. Is there any way to do it without duplicate it and no using any library? Thanks.

Comment: Don't try to make an iOS effect on Android.  We have our own standard effects.  Do things the Android way on Android, otherwise your app looks like a crappy port.

Comment: Actually you'r right but default press effect is not giving an effective feedback to user, when I'm using normal button it's ok but with a button that covered with a full image it is not giving real feedback. Also I tried the answer but same problem low ripple effect not seems good. You have a better idea to do that ? Like FAB button ?